# Azure Data Factory - Dataverse data ingestion and data type mapping

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataverse

We are performing data ingestion of Dataverse[Common data service apps] Entities into ADLS Gen2 using Azure Data Factory. We see few columns missing from Dataverse source which are not copied into ADLS, specifically with Dataverse Data type - Choice.

Are all Dataverse column data types supported by ADF linked service? Please suggest fix or any workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are all Dataverse column data types supported by ADF linked service?

Yes, dataverse supports all column data types.

For missing columns, you should consider the below given points:

- When you copy data from Dynamics, explicit column mapping from Dynamics to sink is optional. But we highly recommend the mapping to ensure a deterministic copy result.
- When the service imports a schema in the authoring UI, it infers the schema. It does so by sampling the top rows from the Dynamics query result to initialize the source column list. In that case, columns with no values in the top rows are omitted. The same behavior also applies to data preview and copy executions if there is no explicit mapping. You can review and add more columns into the mapping, which are honored during copy runtime.

To consume the dataverse choices using ADF, you should use `data flow` activity and use the `derived transformation` because choice values are written as an integer label and not a text label to maintain consistency during edits. The integer-to-text label mapping is stored in the `Microsoft.Athena.TrickleFeedService/table-EntityMetadata.json` file.

Refer this [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-choices-adf#consuming-dataverse-choices-with-azure-data-factory) to implement the same.

Comment: Thanks Utkarsh, I will try and revert to you

Comment: Sure @Akshat!!!

Comment: Thanks Utkarsh, mapping of data types worked with ADF Data Flow

Comment: great! good to know that.